# PHP scandir on external hard drive stops at root directory

Tags: php, apache, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have tried looking for an answer all across Google and here but none have helped thus far..

I have a raspberry pi with raspbian (debian) for an OS that has an external hard drive attached to it via USB. I have mounted it and share it through my network. The drive is mounted to be "/media/Backup". I can access files and folders on the drive without any issues from both the server side and on any computer on the network.

I am also trying to host a webserver that will display the first 2 levels of directories that are on the hard drive.  If I use this code below in a PHP file:

```
$dir    = '/media';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);
```

the results are:

```
.
..
Backup
```

So far, everything works fine.. Now onto the problem. If I try to use this code:

```
$dir    = '/media/Backup';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);
```

it will result in no files/folders found.

I am unsure if this is a problem within PHP or within Debian in the way the drive is accessed.

I am tagging this under both categories since I am unsure of what the problem is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Perhaps something is wrong with my Apache access level for the drives?

Comment: It sounds like the user that apache runs as doesn't have permission to access that drive.

Comment: I was thinking that too from researching.. The current user for apache is www-data and the group is also www-data. Samba that hosts is under the user pi (since its a raspberry pi and pi has root). Whenever I change apache user and group to equal pi and try and restart apache it tells me that the user doesn't have access to the apache folder..

Comment: For pretty obvious reasons; Apache needs to be able to read its configuration files etc in order to start up.  The simple and straightforward solution would be to change the permissions of `/media/Backup` to allow `www-data` read and execute access (or everyone, if that turns out to be tricky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it turns out that I did meed to add permission for user "www-data" to have access to my external drives. For future people who have this problem, here is what I did.

I first created a directory (which will represent the drive once done mounting) using:

```
sudo mkdir /media/HD2
```

Once the directory is made then you can now mount the drive to it:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/HD2
```

where /dev/sdb1 is my drive.

Next I add an entry to fstab for the drive:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

I **add another entry** to the file like this:

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/HD2    vfat    permissions,defaults,auto    0    0
```

Use vfat for fat32 file systems and ntfs if the drive is that.  Don't use any spaces;use tabs.

Save  fstab.
Lastly run this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/HD2
```

This allows all files and folders inside HD2 to be accessed by the user www-data which includes apache.